# What does .map do when object are passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, redis

I was going through Advance NodeJS course by Stephen Colbert where I encountered a code which looks like this

```
const cacheValue = await client.get(key)

    if (cacheValue) {
    const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue)
    console.log("this is doc:", doc)
    if (Array.isArray(doc)) {
        const doc1 = doc.map(d => new this.model(d))
        console.log("this is doc1:", doc1)
        return doc1
    }
    return this.model(doc)
}
```

Here, Stephen was talking about redis (which I think might not be highly relevant here), He mentioned that we can be getting a single blog and group of blogs.

So when we are getting a group of blogs we will check if it is an array, and then map it  `const doc1 = doc.map(d => new this.model(d))`

Now, I am unable get my head around that why won't just `return this.model(doc)` work? like why do we need to do  `if (Array.isArray(doc)) {`

also I am unable to see any difference between `console.log("this is doc:", doc)` and `console.log("this is doc1:", doc1)` and hence what is the difference between our `doc` and `doc1` here?

Comment: If it's an *array* of "doc" objects, the code makes a new model for each one of them.

Comment: And nore that `doc1` is an *array* of model objects.

Comment: Stephen Colbert teaches JavaScript?!